# Can't enter the home page, always directing back to login page

Tags: php, session

As this page is owned by it users, so it has each credentials to enter it which it is by using login form of php (that's what I know so far, I am not very good in php, to be honest).

The problem I do really guess about this must be in the using of session function (and this is the most complicated things to me know, I am not very familiar of using this.)

In the config of the form, I set the session like this (Well, I just copy paste the code from somewhhere) as follow:

```
// User Redirect Conditions will go here
if($count==1)

{
    // Save type and other information in Session for future use.
    $_SESSION[type]=$row[0];
    $_SESSION[Region]=$row[1];
    $_SESSION[myemail]=$myemail;

    // if user type is ACTAdmin only then he can access protected page.
    if($row[0] == 'ACTAdmin') { 
        header( "location:index.php");  
    }
    else { 
        header( "location:login.html");  
    }

}

else 
{
header("location:login.html");
}
// Closing MySQL database connection 
$dbh = null;
```

---

---

In the head of the home page (and in each all related pages), I write a session start there like this:

```
<?php 
include('UserSessionAdmin.php');
?>
```

---

---

In which it will get the data from UserSessionAdmin.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION[type]!='ACTAdmin'){
header('location:login.html');
exit();
}
include('configPDO.php');
?>
```

---

---

What is included in the configPDO.php is here:

```
<?php
// mysql hostname
$hostname = 'mysql.com';
// mysql username
$username = 'alkushh';
// mysql password
$password = 'alkush';
// Database Connection using PDO
try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=user", $username, $password);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

---

---

It's been more than two days for me just to solve it but I don't have any idea how to. Some people who are experts in here may help me with this thing, please.

Thank you and regards,

---

---

Here is the full script that define the $count==1

```
<?php
// Start Session because we will save some values to session varaible.
session_start();

// include connection file
include("configPDO.php");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword
$myemail=$_POST['myemail']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// We Will prepare SQL Query
$STM = $dbh->prepare("SELECT Type,Region FROM user WHERE myemail = :myemail AND mypassword = :mypassword");

// bind paramenters, Named paramenters alaways start with colon(:)
   $STM->bindParam(':myemail', $myemail);
   $STM->bindParam(':mypassword', $mypassword);

// For Executing prepared statement we will use below function
   $STM->execute();

// Count no. of records 
   $count = $STM->rowCount();

//just fetch. only gets one row. So no foreach loop needed :)
  $row  = $STM -> fetch();

// User Redirect Conditions will go here
   if($count==1)
   .....
   .....
```

[image]

Comment: Your session variable needs to be a String. Use **$_SESSION['type']=$row[0];** instead of **$_SESSION[type]=$row[0];**.

Comment: how about the region and the last line?

Comment: Exactly the same. All you session variables need to be declared as Strings :)

Comment: I have done what you suggest and what @Justinas say too, but it still direct me back to the login page.

Comment: In your first file you have **if($count==1)**. However, $count is not defined so it will always return false and go to the 'else' in the 'if'. When a user logs in, you can create a session with credentials. E.g.: $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 'true';. Then you can check on every page if the $_SESSION['loggedin'] exists. If so, you do not have to redirect the user.

Comment: I have update the question to define the $count.

Comment: If I was you, I would start from scratch and try to figure it out by myself. I think this code had a lot of stuff you probably won't need :) Ask as many questions as you like and I will answer them with great pleasure in order to help you. Moreover, you will learn a lot more when you don't copy whole functionalities :) My email is on my profile, feel free to use it if necessary.

Comment: Thank for your kindness. I will. But today my time is not for studying it but for creating it because I need to control my website very soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is

```
if ( $count == 1 ) {
    $_SESSION['login_id'] = $row['id']; // i prefer to name it login_id, you can use $row['id'] or $row[0]. but i prefer to write with the column name

    if ( $_SESSION['login_id'] == 1 ) { // it means if login id = 1 then go to index.php
        header("location: index.php");  
    } else { 
        header("location: login.html");  
    }
}

else { header("location: login.html"); }
```

i cut session region because you didnt have a region column and also i cut session myemail because you didnt need it

---

UserSessionAdmin.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ( $_SESSION['login_id'] == 0 || $_SESSION['login_id'] == '' ) {
        header('location: login.html');
        exit();
    }

    require_once('configPDO.php');
?>
```

Comment: What if the login ID is not 1 because you know the people who will login to it is not always have the ID of 1? I have not tried it, I will let you know if it works.

Comment: Now I can enter the index page without login.

Comment: Then just change it to if ( $_SESSION['login_id'] > 0 )

Comment: it still directs back to login page. :(

Comment: Really? For the fetch you already make it like this right? $row = $STM->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: Yes, I have done it all, but still it directs me back to login page. here: http://cms.jakarta-digital-agency.com/login.html email:alkasih_07@yahoo.com password: thebest1

Comment: Do you have a team viewer? I will remote your computer and check whats going on

Comment: change this $STM = $dbh->prepare("SELECT Type,Region FROM user WHERE myemail = :myemail AND mypassword = :mypassword");

to this
$STM = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE myemail = :myemail AND mypassword = :mypassword");

Comment: It works now! Thanks. But I have a new question which is to show the username. please be referred to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137454/display-username-in-index-page

Answer (score -1):

Please turn on your error reporting to see, that there is no constants such as `type`, `Region`, `myemail`. Use `"` or `'` around parameter of session:

```
if (strcmp($_SESSION['type'], 'ACTAdmin') !== 0) {
    header('location:login.html');
    exit();
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't solve it, I even have edit it as how suggested by @ThomasBormans

Comment: @AlKush Where are you defining `$count` that you use in first example of code?

Comment: @AlKush Does your database name really is `user` or it's table name?

Comment: Yes, my database name is `user` there, which it means that my database name is the same with the `table` name.

Comment: @AlKush Check if your `$count` is equal to 1, also check what you get from database, check if query is correct (run query directly to mysql too)

Comment: I have check it, and the login result is success, however when it comes to the index page, the index page send it back to the login page.

Comment: Which it means here that the session between the config of the login form is not working well with the index page.

Comment: I guess There is a conflict between the session.

Comment: I have tried to make different page to direct it if the user is not logged in (which it is the login2.html) Pay attention to the number 2 of the file, which is different from the origin login page.  `session_start();
if($_SESSION[type]!='ACTAdmin'){
header('location:login2.html');
exit();` but when I submit the login.html, the index page send it to the login2.html