# Display Username in Index page

Tags: php, mysql, session

I know there are so many questions about this in SO. However, the code I have is a little different from there.

What I have is the login page, in which I have to login first to enter the index page.

First, I want to say that this code I have from someone was not working a few days ago. But when I check it again today, unbelievable it is working now.

So, today I have two questions here, as follows:

---

1. I want to show the user information in the index page. Actually I want to show only the username. However, as I don't have username row in the table of the database, I will accept it for a moment if it will only be able to show user email.

---

2. I want some experts here to review the code I have. As what I have mentioned above, the code a few days ago is not working. And today it works without there is single thing I have changed.

---

The important question here is the question number one, which is to show the user information.

Here is the code I have:

**1. Index.php**

```
<?php
include('UserSessionAdmin.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>DASHBOARD</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"/>


</head>

<body>
<?php echo "$myemail";?>
```

---

**2. UserSessionAdmin.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if ( $_SESSION['login_id'] == 0 || $_SESSION['login_id'] == '' ) {
    header('location: login.html');
    exit();
}

require_once('configPDO.php');
?>
```

---

**3. login.html**

```
                <div id="login-form">
                <form method="post" action="CheckLogin.php">
                    <span class="identity">E-mail</span>
                        <input type="text" id="myemail" name="myemail" class="text" />
                    <span class="identity">Password</span>
                        <input type="text" id="mypassword" name="mypassword" class="text" />
                    <p id="button">
                        <input type="submit"/></p> 
                </form>
            </div>
```

**4. CheckLogin.php**

```
<?php
// Start Session because we will save some values to session varaible.
session_start();

   include("configPDO.php");

   $myemail=$_POST['myemail']; 
   $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

   $STM = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE myemail = :myemail AND mypassword = :mypassword");

   $STM->bindParam(':myemail', $myemail);
   $STM->bindParam(':mypassword', $mypassword);

   $STM->execute();

   $count = $STM->rowCount();

   $row  = $STM -> fetch();

   if($count==1)

   {
     $_SESSION['login_id']=$row['id'];

    if($_SESSION['login_id'] == 1) { 
        header( "location:index.php");  
    }
    else { 
        header( "location:login3.html");  
    }

}

else 
{
header("location:login4.html");
}

$dbh = null;
?>
```

---

---

Thank you for all your help. Cheers and regards,

Comment: Your index.php uses a variable which is not even defined. You have to set the user information in you session to display them in your index.php. You struggle with the very basics.

Comment: @eeK that's what I want to know. :)

Comment: you can set the email just as you set the id of the user ($_SESSION['email']=$row['email'];), where $row['email'] stands for the column name of the table you want to use. In your index.php you can then just output your $_SESSION['email'].

Comment: Can I output that in the body tag? For example. `<span> Your email is $_SESSION['email']</span>`

Comment: When you have set it in CheckLogin.php you can use it in you index.php like this: <?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?>.

Stackoverflow should not be a place for people to write your code. Try to understand the very basics and write your own code before asking questions.

Comment: @eeK but there are many people in SO who are willing to write codes for me. Please, if you don't want to help, then I dont need your help anyway, and just get away from my question. :)

Comment: I want to help. You should have noticed that all the answers below just copied what I already told in the comments. Whatever...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CheckLogin.php**

```
if ( $count == 1 )  {
    $_SESSION['login_id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username']; // added

    if ( $_SESSION['login_id'] != '' || $_SESSION['login_id'] > 0 ) { // edited
        header("location: index.php");  
    } else { 
        header("location: login3.html");  
    }
}
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php
    require_once 'UserSessionAdmin.php'; // edited
    $username = $_SESSION['username']; // added
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>DASHBOARD</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<?php echo $username; ?> // edited
```

Comment: I just remember that when the code was not working yesterday is before I deleted the row username in the table. And now I want to add the row for username again, but I am afraid that the code is not working again?

Comment: no its ok, theres no problem with username column, because you call it by columns name, not by the index.

Comment: thanks, I will give it a try soon. But can you please have a look to the answer by Mohit and my comment there...

Comment: the answer is simple, just change **$_SESSION['login_id'] == 1** to **$_SESSION['login_id'] != '' || $_SESSION['login_id'] != 0**

Comment: So, I only have to change it in the UserSessionAdmin.php, how about the line in CheckLogin.php?

Comment: yes you only have to change it, just copy it from UserSessionAdmin.php to CheckLogin.php, because they were in same condition anyway

Comment: Like this: `
    if($_SESSION['login_id'] == !) { 
        header( "location:index.php");  
    }
` In which here I change 1 to !?

Comment: this **$_SESSION['login_id'] == 1** to this one **$_SESSION['login_id'] != '' || $_SESSION['login_id'] > 0**

Comment: I am confused. I think the code you give is written in the UserSessionAdmin.php, and not in the CheckLogin.php. Could you please make it in your answer so that it will be much clearer for me to achieve this? I am sorry for disturbing you. Thanks for the kindness help.

Comment: It works well in showing the username. But when I try to login from another computer with another account (username and email), it still always shows the username with the ID of 1. What's wrong?

Comment: Really? Your sql query already correct .. have you update it to your website? Let me try it

Comment: I have two users: First: `"id:1; username:alkasih; email:alkasih_07@yahoo.com; password:thebest1;"` and Second:  `"id:2; username:Yahya; email:yahya@yahoo.com; password:thebest2;"`  To be pleased to check it here. http://new.jakarta-digital-agency.com/index.php

Comment: Its already dynamic right? The name in the index .. because theres no problem anymore

Comment: What do you mean it's already dynamic? When I enter the account of Yahya, it doesn't show the name of yahya but alkasih.

Comment: For calling the $_SESSION username in the index.php .. you already make it with echo $_SESSION username right? Theres no error anymore on your script

Comment: Or can you download a team viewer? So I can look your code and change it live

Comment: I have echo it, and it appears in the corner-left-side of the menu before Dashboard menu. Can you please login with email yahya@yahoo.com and password thebest2, and see that the menu in the left side still show the username of alkasih, not yahya.

Answer (score 2):

First Change you have to made is in Checklogin.php File:

**1) CheckLogin.php:**

```
if($_SESSION['login_id'] == 1) { 
    $_SESSION['myemail'] = $myemail;
    header( "location:index.php");  
}
else { 
    header( "location:login3.html");  
}
```

Second Change you have to made is in index.php File:

**2) Index.php**

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['myemail'];?>
```

But Actually there is a problem in CheckLogin.php file where you are checking the login_id. Is all the users in your database have login_id is equal to 1. And for what purpose you have added the login_id field in your database table. According to this code only those users which have login_id is equal to 1 and correct username & password is going to able to login. Otherwise even if he enters the right username and password will not be able to login which thus happening in your case before that i think so.

Comment: What I have to change so that not only the user who has the Id 1 who can login?

Comment: You just have to remove this code "if($_SESSION['login_id'] == 1)" because you are already checking the username and password above. But if you are using it for any purpose then check it for what purpose you are using this check or if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method that you can use to pass through the e-mail and have the username returned like so:

```
function usernameFromEmail($email) {
    $username = $db->prepare('SELECT username FROM table WHERE email = ?');
    $username->execute(array($email));

    return $username->fetch();
}
```

You can then call this method and pass through the e-mail and you'll have the username.

Replace table with the name of the table, email with the true name of the column, and username with the true name of the column.